# `ncurses` function `wgetstr` is modifying my variables

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, ncurses

**SOLUTION** Apparently, the `wgetstr` function does *not* make a new buffer. If the second argument is called `data` and has size `n` and you give an input of more than `n` characters, it will access and overwrite parts in memory that do not belong to `data`, such as the place in memory where `cursorY` is stored. To make everything work, I declared `data` with `char data[] = "        ";` (eight spaces) and wrote `wgetnstr(inputWin, data, 8);`.

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

It seems that the `ncurses` function `wgetstr` is literally changing the values of my variables. In a function called `playGame`, I have a variable called `cursorY` (of type `int`) which is adjusted whenever I press the up- or down-arrow on my keyboard (this works fine).

Please take a look at this code (`inputWin` is of type `WINDOW*`):

```
mvprintw(0, 0, (to_string(cursorY)).c_str());
refresh();
usleep(500000);

wgetstr(inputWin, data);

mvprintw(0, 0, (to_string(cursorY)).c_str());
refresh();
usleep(500000);
```

Suppose I move the cursor to the 6th row and then press Enter (which causes this piece of code to be executed). There are two things I can do:

- Input just 1 character. After both `refresh` calls, the value 6 is shown on the screen (at position (0, 0)).
- Input 2 or more characters. In this case, after the first `refresh` call I simply get 6, but after the second, I magically get 0.

The first two lines after the code above are

```
noecho();
_theView -> _theActualSheet -> putData(cursorY-1, cursorX/9 - 1, data);
```

(don't worry about the acutal parameters: the math regarding them checks out). While I'm in `putData`, I get a `Segmentation fault`, and `gdb` says that the first argument of `putData` was -1, so then `cursorY` had to be 0 (the first two arguments of `putData` are used to access a two-dimensional array using `SheetCells[row][column]`, where `row` and `column` are, respectively, the first and second formal parameter of `putData`).

Clearly, `wgetstr` modifies the value of `cursorY`. The name of the latter variable doesn't matter: changing it to `cursorrY` or something weird like `monkeyBusiness` (yes I've tried that) doesn't work. What *sort of* works is replacing the piece of code above with

```
mvprintw(0, 0, (to_string(cursorY)).c_str());
refresh();
usleep(500000);

int a = cursorY;
wgetstr(inputWin, data);
cursorY = a;

mvprintw(0, 0, (to_string(cursorY)).c_str());
refresh();
usleep(500000);
```

In both cases I see 6 at the top-left corner of my screen. However, know the string is acting all weird: when I type in `asdf` as my string, then move to the right (i.e., I press the right key on my keyboard), then type in `asdf` again, I get `as^a`.

So basically, I would like to know two things:

- Why the HELL is `wgetstr` changing my variables?
- Why is it only happening when I input more than 1 character?
- What seems to be wrong with `wgetstr` in general? It seems terrible at handling input.

I could try other things (like manually reading in characters and then concatenating `data` with them), but `wgetstr` seems perfect for what I want to do, and there is no reason I should switch here.

Any help is much appreciated. (Keep in mind: I specifically want to know why the value of `cursorY` is being changed. If you would recommend not using `wgetstr` and have a good alternative, please tell me, but I'm most interested in knowing why `cursorY` is being altered.)

**EDIT** The variable `data` is of type `char[]` and declared like so: `char data[] = ""`. I don't "clear" this variable (i.e., remove all "letters"), but I don't think this makes any difference, as I think `wgetstr` just overrides the whole variable (or am I terribly wrong here?).

Comment: What is `data`, and how is it defined? My bet is you fail to initialize it properly, causing `cursorY` to be overwritten accidentally.

Comment: I've edited my question, please take a look at the new part.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN As I said in my original question, renaming the variable `cursorY` to `cursorrY` or even the weirdest names unfortunately doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Looks like @H.Guijt has the right idea. `wgetstr` expects to write to a buffer that _has already been allocated and is long enough for the input string_. You've not done this with `data`, so `wgetstr` is writing over the end of the buffer and into whatever variables were defined next. If your input string were long enough, I'd expect more damage to occur.

Comment: You are proclaiming that a library used without problem for decades has a serious bug that no one has before noticed. Your own description leaves plenty of room that it is an error on your part. **Provide us with a small test case** that demonstrates the bug and we'll see if we can help you figure it out.

Comment: Good ... sorry I missed that sentence.  My next step was to isolate my code from the curses macros.  I refactored the code I wrote that invokes any curses macros directly into a file separate from all the rest of my code.  Only that one file #include ncurses, so the compiler can check for you.  The linker pulls it together.  I had no more macro problems after that.  I wish it had been my first 'solution' to the cursed curses macros.  Good luck.

Comment: @Dúthomhas - while curses 1st release was 23 years ago (according to Wikipedia), the latest stable release was v6.0 / 8 August 2015; only 6 months ago

Comment: @Dúthomhas The wgetstr function may be decades old, but I can see a major security issue in a single glance: it will let you pass unguarded buffers. It should have been deprecated as soon as wgetnstr was introduced.

Comment: Yes, yes, agreed. All such functions are security issues. They've been around for decades and have caused plenty of harm. And as noted, the library is still updated and used regularly. The point stands: unlikely that new user found serious bug; more likely that he is using it wrong.

In any case, I'm glad you figured it out. I missed the one character definition of data.

Answer (score 4):

The buffer you provide for the data, `data`, is defined as being a single character long (only the null-terminator will be there). This means that if you enter any input of one or more characters, you will be writing outside the space provided by data, and thus overwrite something else. It looks like cursorY is the lucky variable that got hit.

You need to make sure that data is at least big enough to handle all inputs. And preferably, you should switch to some input function (like `wgetnstr`) that will let you pass the size of the buffer, otherwise it will always be possible to crash your application by typing enough characters.

Comment: And there is no way to provide a buffer that is always large enough? Like a buffer that grows in size? Unfortunately, `string`s don't work, as `wgetstr` wants a `char*`, and using `data.c_str()` doesn't work either, because the conversion from `const char*` to `char*` is also too much, apparently.

Comment: It just seems too much trouble. You would expect being able to handle input of any length and just expanding the buffer size when needed. Is there nothing I can do? All characters after the 8th are eventually "sliced off" anyway, but I'd like to handle that in a different function (in fact, I have already done so).

Comment: That's the curse of always using C APIs instead of C++ APIs: fixed buffers are everywhere and since there is no meaningful abstraction for them, reallocating them on the fly is basically impossible. But with wgetnstr at least you can avoid crashing for overly-long inputs.

Answer (score 2):

`wgetstr` expects to write the received characters to a preallocated buffer, which should be at least as long as the expected input string. It does not allocate a new buffer for you!

What you've done is provide it with a single byte buffer, and are writing multiple bytes to it. This will stomp over the other variables you've defined in your function after `data`, such as `cursorY`, *regardless of what it is called*. Any changes to variables will in turn change the string that was read in:

```
int a = cursorY;
wgetstr(inputWin, data);
cursorY = a;
```

will write an int value into your string, which is why it is apparently getting corrupted.

What you should actually do is to make `data` actually long enough for the anticipated input, and ideally use something like `wgetnstr` to ensure you don't walk off the end of the buffer and cause damage.